# Drop nans if a value occurs more than once, keep nans if only one row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where most ID's (names) have multiple entries, but some have none.

```
     Name   Fruit
0    Anna     NaN
1    Pete   Apple
2    Pete  Banana
3    Pete     NaN
4    Mark  Orange
5    Mark   Apple
6    Mark  Banana
7    Mark     NaN
8   Roger     NaN
9   Alice   Apple
10  Alice     NaN
11     Jo   Apple
```

If the person only has a nan next to them, I want to keep that nan, but if there are any fruits, I want to delete the nan.

The result would be:

```
     Name   Fruit
0    Anna     NaN
1    Pete   Apple
2    Pete  Banana
4    Mark  Orange
5    Mark   Apple
6    Mark  Banana
8   Roger     NaN
9   Alice   Apple
11     Jo   Apple
```

How do I do this?

I've tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
if df['Name'].value_counts() > 1:
    df=df.dropna(subset=['Name', 'Fruit'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try a combination of `groupby().transform('nunique')` with `.isna()` to filter the data in a nice one liner. I believe this generates the expected output:

```
df.loc[(df.groupby('Name')['Fruit'].transform('nunique') == 0) | (~df['Fruit'].isna()),:]
```

Outputs:

```
     Name   Fruit
0    Anna     NaN
1    Pete   Apple
2    Pete  Banana
4    Mark  Orange
5    Mark   Apple
6    Mark  Banana
8   Roger     NaN
9   Alice   Apple
11     Jo   Apple
```

Comment: Yes this is it, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue to mark it as answered and reward me with some points too!